# Can't select to boot another operative system after installing Ubuntu on a secondary drive

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 machine installed on an SSD, installed another hard disk and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on it. I didn't specified anything when installing, but now it boots directly into Ubuntu. It doesn't give me the option to select which OS to boot.

Comment: Quick question, what do you mean on another hard disk?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on another physical hard disk, different than the drive that I installed Windows on.

Comment: Which hard drive is the "first", from the point of view of the BIOS? Does swapping the cables over cause Windows to boot again?

Comment: There's so much that could be wrong. What is your current drive schema? (`sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo gdisk -l`) The output of `sudo os-prober`. And what is the desired behavior? That you boot into UEFI? GRUB? or just whatever allows you to select what OS to boot from?

Comment: We really need to know if UEFI or BIOS or mixed mode boot. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info You can run from a working Ubuntu install or from LIve installer.

Answer (score 1):

First try to go into your Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Next type in:

```
sudo grub-install
```

wait for that to finish, then do:

```
 sudo grub-update
```

Finally restart your computer and see if the windows 10 shows up in the boot menu, it might say windows 8 loader which is what mine says.If that doesn't work I will look for something else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried to run "sudo grub-install", I got this error message "Install device isn't specified."

what does that mean?

Comment: @superkinhluan you must specify the device: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two options, here they are:

**Option 1.** Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

and type in the following command

```
sudo grub-install
```

once that finishes do:

```
sudo grub-update
```

now restart your computer and you should see a list of operating systems..

Choose whichever you prefer / want.

-

**Option 2.** Power off, and then turn on your computer..

While it is turning on press the <kbd>f12</kbd> button on your keyboard.

You should see a list where you can select windows (using your arrow keys)!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried to run "sudo grub-install", I got this error message "Install device isn't specified." I then tried Option 2, but it still boots directly into Ubuntu.

Comment: One moment let me figure out why

Comment: @superkinhluan try this:   sudo grub-install /dev/sda

Comment: @superkinhluan then do    sudo update-grub

Comment: thanks. I ran those two commands successfully and then restarted. It still boots into Ubuntu directly. I paste the outputs of the commands here:

sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: Sector 32 is already in use by the program `FlexNet'; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
Installation finished. No error reported.

Comment: sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-22-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin

Comment: I tried again and this time I am able to boot into the Grub UI. However, it doesn't offer the choice to boot into Windows. There are only 4 options: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Memory Test (memtest86+), Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Comment: hey @superkinhluan one thing... may have messed up with the command... when you got those warnings, was worried there by the part that said "this may cuase boot problems in the future" so ... if I did give you advice that messed something up I am sorry.... however now that grub is working i feel a little better....

Comment: Are you sure you didnt accidently delete windows?

Comment: try my other method and see if you are able to load into windows from there

Comment: What do you mean by deleting windows? do you mean deleting the Windows partition? I'm sure I didn't because I an still access the Windows drive from Ubuntu.

Comment: I've just retried the F12 method but it didn't work. It paused a few moments and eventually boots into Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: when the computer is booting up does it say to push any other keys for boot menu? maybe delete?   And please, if the commands i told you to run earlier do cause problems in the future, I do apologize

Comment: Sudo Sudo? what...

Answer (score 0):

Enter the boot menu when you're at POST screen and choose your SSD, it should boot into Windows 10 as long as you didn't modify the MBR.
You can as well edit the default boot drive in your BIOS.

Comment: My SSD doesn't appear in the list. :(

Comment: Can you see your SSD in the BIOS?

Comment: yes, I can see it.

Comment: Change the boot order so your PC would boot into the SSD instead of the HDD.